# Cannot run jar file by cliking

Tags: java, eclipse

I am a new in java. I did the export "Runnable JAR file" and it runs on the other computer by clicking .jar file although it has a compiler warning. After I modified my code and exported it again, it didn't run. I have no clue how to investigate the problem. Can anyone give me some direction to solve the problem?

Comment: To start investigating the problem, open a command prompt, navigate to the directory with the jar, and type `java -jar <yourjar.jar>`.  If you can't figure out what the ensuing error message means, please add the message to your question.

Comment: What is your OS? And have you given the permission to execute it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try to run the jar file via command line interface to read possible errors. Start cmd, navigate to .jar-file and type "java -jar FILENAME" (where FILENAME is the name of the jar file). If it's some sort of error you will maybe get some info from the produced log. You can post it here afterwards if it makes no sense for you. Additionally type in "java -version" to obtain version information.